# Observable Collection binding to autocompleteextender in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a `textbox` and `autocompleteextender` and this `autocompleteextender` servicemethod has a return type of `ObservableCollection<T>.`

When i run the code, the output i am getting is `[object,object]`.

I need to display the value of one field from it.

I am attaching my code below How can I do??

asp.net code

```
<td style="width: 300px; align-content: stretch;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" Width="250px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender Id="AutoCompleteExtender" TargetControlID="txtCity" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCity" UseContextKey="True" runat="server"  ></cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

and my codebehind is

```
 public ObservableCollection<Item> GetCity(string prefixText)
    {
        DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
        ObservableCollection<Item> itemsList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        itemsList = db.SelectItems(prefixText);

        return itemsList;
    }
```

Item Class

```
 public class Item
{
    public Item(string listID, string name,string fullName )
    {
        this.Name1 = name;
        ListID1 = listID;
        FullName1 = fullName;
    }
    public string ListID1 { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string FullName1 { get; set; }
}
```